# Cannot rotate xticks when using two y axes

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

For some reason, when I create a plot that uses two y-axes I can no longer rotate the xticks using `plt.xticks(rotation=45)`. Are the xticks controlled differently when using two y-axis?

```
plt.figure()
ax = sns.boxplot(
    data=df,
    x='x',
    y='y',
)

ax2 = ax.twinx() 
ax2 =  sns.scatterplot(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    ax=ax2,
    data=df2,
    legend=False,
)

plt.tight_layout()
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True, bottom=False, right=False)

# seems to have no effect
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You're using object oriented axes, (e.g. `ax`, `ax2`), as such, you should reference the correct axes when changing the rotation, and you need to set the rotation before creating twinx

Answer (score 0):

As commented, referencing the first axis solves the issue. The following code does what I was hoping for:

```
plt.figure()
ax = sns.boxplot(
    data=df,
    x='x',
    y='y',
)

ax2 = ax.twinx() 
ax2 =  sns.scatterplot(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    ax=ax2,
    data=df2,
    legend=False,
)

plt.tight_layout()
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True, bottom=False, right=False)

# now rotates axis labels
ax.set_xticklabels(labels_list, rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Technically, placing `plt.xticks(rotation=45)` just before `ax2 = ax.twinx()` will also work, because `ax` is the current axes. But sticking with the object oriented approach makes the code more clear when working with multiple axes.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I figured that would do the trick before posting this question, but for some reason just placing it before defining the new axis did not work for me.

Comment: Sometimes seaborn behaves unexpectedly with the objects.